# couchDB update attachments

Tags: couchdb

Can I update the attachments of an existing document without uploading them again?

I tried:

```php
<?php
    $json = '
    {
        "_id":"attachment_doc",
        "_rev":'.$rev.',
        "_attachments":
        {
            "free-wallpaper-31.jpg":
            {
                "revpos":3,
                "content_type":"image\/jpeg",
                "data": "'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('free-wallpaper-31.jpg')).'"
            }
        }
    }
';

$doc = $couchdb->doc_upload_attachments('16beb67b990604791b3ffde7dd000576', $json);
var_dump($doc);
?>
```

But that overwrites the existing attachments and stores the document with a new revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with the API for PHP, but in general in CouchDB REST API you can upload an attachment without uploading the document and other previously uploaded attachments. Take a look at [attachment section of API chapter](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/api.html#attachments) in The Definite Guide. In command line:

```
curl -vX PUT http://localhost:5984/YOUR_DB/YOUR_DOCUMENT/YOUR_ATTACHMENT.jpg?rev=REVISION_OF_THE_DOCUMENT_BEFORE_UPLOADING_AN_ATTACHMENT --data-binary @FILE_ON_THE_DISK.JPG -H "Content-Type: image/jpg"
```

It works for me :) And yes, the revision of the document has to change when uploading succeeds. If you have trouble uploading with the bindings in your language, just upload it with standard HTTP API.