# curl syntax error: append couchdb document failed with "conflict"?

Tags: linux, curl, docker, couchdb, document

I've installed couchdb and mingw64 on my windows 10, I can use futon to operate my couch db, no problem. Then I tried command line using curl.
 I used curl to create database named "my_database", I can query it using "GET":

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/my_database/002
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    81  100    81    0     0    397      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   397{"_id":"002","_rev":"1-5e653801ca3cefde8abb6492ae3bcbcd","name":"mesi","age":23}
```

But I cannot do any data update, seems my curl syntax had problem:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_database/002/msg.jpg?res=1-5e653801ca3cefde8abb6492ae3bcbcd --data-binary @/e/msg.jpg -H "ContentType:image/jpg"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 14  910k  100    58   14  128k     58   128k  0:00:07 --:--:--  0:00:07  125M{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

I know the jpg file is there:

```
$ ls /e/msg.jpg
/e/msg.jpg
```

Why I cannot update the jpg document as attachement? I guess I might have some syntax error using curl or couchdb, but how to fix it?

Using futon_db: created document, but what's the URL resource name of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you update a document/Attachment in CouchDB, you need to specify the revision (otherwise it cause conflicts). I guess that you only forgot to write **rev** properly (you wrote res).

Syntax taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712459/couchdb-update-attachments) :

```
curl -vX PUT http://localhost:5984/YOUR_DB/YOUR_DOCUMENT/YOUR_ATTACHMENT.jpg?rev=REVISION_OF_THE_DOCUMENT_BEFORE_UPLOADING_AN_ATTACHMENT --data-binary @FILE_ON_THE_DISK.JPG -H "Content-Type: image/jpg"
```